# SET /P for any input (or work around)

Tags: batch-file, set

Im using a script to start various applications needed when I live stream, and am using a

`SET /P $headerTxt="Please enter Stream Header text:"`

While testing other features I used the input `Testign for all` and learned about code insertion first hand.

The whole piece of code is as follows, after which `$headerTxt` is no longer used.

`:SetOBSTitleTxt
   SET /P "$headerTxt"="Please enter Stream Header text:"
   IF DEFINED %$headerTxt% (
   ECHO %$headerTxt%> "%$obsFilePath%%$headerTxtFile%"
   )`

I am looking for a way to capture the entire input to a string, where a user inputting a command would not be parsed as a command rather entered into the string.  I can handle telling users they need to escape for `& | < >` but I'd rather not limit the words they can use.

Thanks in advance for your time and considerations.

Ashlee

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using **Delayed Expansion** will prevent the scenarios with special characters that you are trying to avoid.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /p "$headerTxt=Please enter Stream Header text:"
echo !$headerTxt!
endlocal
exit /b 0
```

Also, here is a simple Input routine that will continually prompt until input is given.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
call :Input $headerTxt "Please enter Stream Header text:"
echo !$headerTxt!
endlocal
exit /b 0

:Input <Var> [Prompt]
2>nul set /p "%~1=%~2"
if not defined %~1 = goto Input
exit /b 0
```

Comment: Thank you much, sorry for the delay in responding, another project gained precedence to personal work.  <3

Answer (score 0):

First, `IF DEFINED %$headerTxt%` should be `IF DEFINED $headerTxt` (no `%` characters).

Second, it is a fact of life using cmd.exe that certain characters get interpreted a certain way (e.g., `>` is interpreted as output redirection).

If you can use a freeware download program, you can use the editv32.exe or editv64.exe to read this input instead of `set /p`. It will automatically insert the `^` escape character for you. For example:

```
editv64 -p "Please enter stream header text:" $headerTxt
```

You can download editv32.exe (32-bit) and editv64.exe (64-bit) from here:

http://www.westmesatech.com/editv.html